# Asterisk/Wildcard in CSS selector name

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I could've sworn I saw an advanced CSS rule that uses an asterisk in the selector name. I'm using Bootstrap and I have a couple different divs within a parent div like so:

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        TEST
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        TEST
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to use something like:

```
div.example div.col-sm-*{
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

I know it wouldn't kill me to add each rule side by side but I thought I had seen some thing like that done in the past and would like to learn the short hand for the future if it exists. I also tried something like:

```
div.example div.col-sm-[*]{
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: div[class^="col-sm-"] { /* all your styles here */ }

Comment: To avoid future confusion, you should say "wildcard" instead of "asterisk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking of an attribute selector:

```
div.example div[class*="col-sm-"]{
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Assuming the only class that each of those `div`s will have is a column class, that will work. Alternatively use `^=` in lieu of `*=` to indicate that the `class` attribute value *starts* with that string.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was trying to think of. Any idea on browser compatibility with this? I'm not having great luck Googling this for some reason.

Comment: The only browser that doesn't support it at all is IE6 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
.example div{
//rule
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It does not answer the question about using * in the selector name exactly, but it provides a simpler solution according the example code exposed in the question.